# How to have the HUD search all resources?

Tags: hud

On the 12.04 Beta, if you click on the alt key, HUD appears and on bottom of the screen you have four icons. There's an arrow pointing down onto the HOME icon by default. If you start typing you can only see what's available within that resource. If you wanted to search for videos you have to click on the video icon and then type in your query. Is there a way to have it search ALL resources? I'd like to be less mouse dependent.

When you do get results, is there a way to assign a number to the results? I can move the cursor down and once I've highlighted it hit enter but assigning a number would get to the result faster.

Answer (score 1):

In 12.04, you can have Unity search all your files, rather than just ones that have been logged by zeitgeist, by adding the lense testing ppa and new unity lens files:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:unity-team/lenses-testing
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install unity-lens-files
```